# Reset System.Lazy

Tags: c#-4.0

In a business class I have :

```
 class Employee{

      public Employee() {
          m_Manager = new Lazy<Manager>( () => return myRepository.GetManager(ManagerId); );
      }
      public int ManagerId { get; set;}
      private Lazy<Manager> m_Manager;
      public Manager Manager { 
          get {
               return m_Manager.Value;
          }
      }
 }
```

This is working correctly, the custom repository is called only if accessing the Manager property.
Now I want to "reset" my manager property if the `ManagerId` changed. How to do that ?

I can do :

```
 class Employee{

      public Employee() {
          m_Manager = new Lazy<Manager>( () => return myRepository.GetManager(ManagerId); );
      }
      private int m_ManagerId;
      public int ManagerId { 
          get { return m_ManagerId;}
          set { 
               if(m_ManagerId != value)
               {
                    m_ManagerId = value;
                    m_Manager = new Lazy<Manager>( () => return myRepository.GetManager(ManagerId); );
               }
          }
      }
      private Lazy<Manager> m_Manager;
      public Manager Manager { 
          get {
               return m_Manager.Value;
          }
      }
 }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do that ? Isn't there a `m_Manager.Reset()` or something like this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Lazy<T>` does not define a Reset() method.  What you've implemented looks fine I think.

Comment: I agree that the general approach is fine, but suggest extracting the duplicated Lazy<Manager> initialization code into a shared method.

Answer (score 10):

If you are happy with using undocumented behaviour and private fields, here is a method to do it:

```
public static void ResetPublicationOnly<T>(this Lazy<T> lazy)
{
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    LazyThreadSafetyMode mode = (LazyThreadSafetyMode)typeof(Lazy<T>).GetProperty("Mode", flags).GetValue(lazy, null);
    if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ResetPublicationOnly only works for Lazy<T> with LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly");

    typeof(Lazy<T>).GetField("m_boxed", flags).SetValue(lazy, null); 
}
```

And some test for usage:

```
Lazy<string> val = new Lazy<string>(() => "hola" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);

val.ResetPublicationOnly(); //reset before initialized
var str1 = val.Value;
val.ResetPublicationOnly(); //reset after initialized

var str2 = val.Value;

Assert.AreNotEqual(str1, str2);
```

**EDIT: Deprecated!** This solution no longer works as pointed by Keith. We have build owr own ResetLazy in Signum Framework

```
public interface IResetLazy
{
    void Reset();
    void Load();
    Type DeclaringType { get; }
}

[ComVisible(false)]
[HostProtection(Action = SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Resources = HostProtectionResource.Synchronization | HostProtectionResource.SharedState)]
public class ResetLazy<T>: IResetLazy
{
    class Box
    {
        public Box(T value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public readonly T Value;
    }

    public ResetLazy(Func<T> valueFactory, LazyThreadSafetyMode mode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly, Type declaringType = null)
    {
        if (valueFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("valueFactory");

        this.mode = mode;
        this.valueFactory = valueFactory;
        this.declaringType = declaringType ?? valueFactory.Method.DeclaringType;
    }

    LazyThreadSafetyMode mode; 
    Func<T> valueFactory;

    object syncLock = new object();

    Box box;

    Type declaringType; 
    public Type DeclaringType
    {
        get { return declaringType; }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            var b1 = this.box;
            if (b1 != null)
                return b1.Value;

            if (mode == LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
            {
                lock (syncLock)
                {
                    var b2 = box;
                    if (b2 != null)
                        return b2.Value;

                    this.box = new Box(valueFactory());

                    return box.Value;
                }
            }

            else if (mode == LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly)
            {
                var newValue = valueFactory(); 

                lock (syncLock)
                {
                    var b2 = box;
                    if (b2 != null)
                        return b2.Value;

                    this.box = new Box(newValue);

                    return box.Value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var b = new Box(valueFactory());
                this.box = b;
                return b.Value;
            }
        }
    }


    public void Load()
    {
        var a = Value;
    }

    public bool IsValueCreated
    {
        get { return box != null; }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.None)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                this.box = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.box = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a bit tricky, but as it can be encapsulated into an extention method, this could highly simplify my code. thx

Comment: hope your not in a tight loop

Comment: looks like they have made some changes to the Lazy<T> source code. This method no longer works and an exception will be thrown

Comment: It's true, we have build or own ResetLazy<T> implementation

Comment: A great example of why not to use undocumented behaviour and private fields!

Comment: @Olmo In `ResetLazy`, why do you force `T` to be a reference type?

Comment: I think you're right this is legacy because there was no Box class before

Comment: Far better to just reassign the variable as per the code in the question... simple AND reliable, easily made thread safe.

Comment: Mmmm... it depends. It forces the client code to factor-out the lazy instantantiation (to avoid duplication), and makes a global 'Reset all caches' buton more difficult. But could work in many cases.

Comment: ResetLazy calling `valueFactory()` inside of the `lock (syncLock)` in the `ExecutionAndPublication` section is a deadlock waiting to happen - the coder just has to accidentally attempt to access `Value` in the initialization code. The code could use Monitor.Enter/Exit with some try/finally and an additional flag to note that the value is getting initialized

Comment: I think the same thread is allowed to take the same lock twice, it this is what you mean, but there are fundamental differences in how ResetLazy works compared to https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs,6ee8823dee194815 and that makes me nervous. Anyway I'm using it a lot without problems.

Comment: If you have Two ResetLazy depending on each other and they are accessed by threads at the same time and both are set to ExecutionAndPublication then yes, there will be a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Before you re-instanciate the Lazy you can also add a condition for reseting only if it was initalized "if(m_Manager.IsValueCreated)".

Comment: That would create a race condition - if another thread had started to create the value, and already read the (original) ManagerId, and at that moment the ManagerId is changed, then you would see IsValueCreated as false, and not re-instantiate the Lazy<>. Moments later the other thread successfully creates the Manager object, and all subsequent callers receive the wrong manager object. With the original code, only callers who at least started to access the Employee object before the ManagerId changed would see the old Manager object.